# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validationEngine'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask about my problem.
I am getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.validationEngine-en.js:192
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validationEngine'
```

When I tried to validate my form using jquery validation engine plugin. I followed the instruction but I don't know why am I getting this error. I also double check the path and it is working also. Here's my sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validationEngine.js'></script>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/css/validationEngine.jquery.css' />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="formID" method="post" action="submit.action">
            <input value="someone@nowhere.com" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#formID").validationEngine();
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to load jquery before you load the jquery plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your `jQuery library` at the top before loading `validation` script.

As it has has dependencies on `jQuery library` so you can not use `$` or `jQuery` before defining them so load library first.

Load this way :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/js/jquery.validationEngine.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://localhost/mycrud/./third_party/jquery-validation/css/validationEngine.jquery.css' />
```